# Generate PDF from a view but content is not in English

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate a PDF doc from mvc4 view but none English characters do not display or display as gibberish(for English it works fine).

I tried to use pdfRazor and itext but only English chars are shown on screen. I'm open to any solution even for generating string from the view and then render PDF (that also didn't work for me).
If anyone was able to genrate pdf from mvc view please please let me know. 
I guess the issue with itextsharp is the basefont - i don't mind using other solution.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What are "English characters"? A through Z should work, but Umlaute (ÄÖÜäöü) and ß should also work (standard PDF encoding is much like ANSI encoding). If not, there is an encoding problem between your application and the PDF library. For special characters (e.g. Eastern European) you have to specify that you want a PDF file with Unicode encoding (I don't know how to get that with itext or pdfRazor).

Comment: I meant Hebrew letters. I'm pretty sure that the issue is with the font base when using iText (I don't really care which font is it). I couldn't find a way to specify the font on the <iText>. I don't mind to use other solution as long as it supports Hebrew and it is not executable like Rotativa.

Answer (score 0):

You can create PDF with mixed English and Hebrew characters , for this you need to specify the font.(you can downlaod the font files and keep it in your in your application)

check the below link, you can use the code lines in the samples

[java itext create pdf with hebrew (rtl) and english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855078/java-itext-create-pdf-with-hebrew-rtl-and-english)

[My Hebrew Text in iText is left-aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954126/my-hebrew-text-in-itext-is-left-aligned)

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-display-Arabic-td3400141.html

[Change direction of written text for Hebrew letters iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173167/change-direction-of-written-text-for-hebrew-letters-itext)

Comment: I know how to set the font (as described in the article) but i want to specify the font (or what else needed) in the XML <itext>. I prefer to have xml schema with all the definitions and not define that in code.